# html javascript php zip code data validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

I am adding a data validation to my code. I want to make sure the event title is not blank, and the zip code entered is valid. The javascript does not work. Can you tell me why?

```
<form name="form1" action="organize.php" onSubmit="return validateform1();" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">            

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="event_title">Event Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="event_title" id="dob" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="dob" />
    </div>

    <script language="javascript">

        function validateform1(){        

            var zipcode = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;        
            if(document.form1.event_title.value==""){
                alert("Enter a title");
                return false;
            }        
            else if((!document.form1.zip.value.match(zipcode)){  
                alert("wrong zip format");  
                return false;  
            }  
    </script>

</form>
```

Comment: What if they live in a country that doesn't have ZIP codes? Hope this is local-only?

Comment: what is the zip-code format u want to validate???

Comment: @WayneWhitty yes for now!

Comment: @NoobEditor the format is either 5 digits or 5+4 digits: 99999 or 99999-9999

Comment: Probably doesn't help that your ZIP field has `id="dob"`. Anyway, what do you mean by "The javascript does not work."? What happens when it runs, do you get an error reported in the browser's console, or does something happen but the wrong thing, or...?

Comment: @AaronF : why do u have `<script>` inside `<form>`, and `onSubmit` needs a `submit button`, where is it in your form??? :)

Comment: @nnnnnn I use id="dob" for formatting with css. Actually it gives me the error message when function validateform1(){ if(document.form1.event_title.value==""){
    alert("Enter a title");
    return false;
    }

Comment: It is invalid html to have more than one element with the same id, even ignoring that it is confusing to use an abbreviation that normally means "date of birth" for a ZIP field and a title field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably doesn't help that your ZIP field has `id="dob"`, but I think the main issue is that your function is missing a closing `}`, and your `else if ((` has an extra `(`. Try this:

```
function validateform1() {

    var zipcode = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    if (document.form1.event_title.value == "") {
        alert("Enter a title");
        return false;
    } else if (!document.form1.zip.value.match(zipcode)) {
        alert("wrong zip format");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have missed closing `)` in this line:

```
else  if((!document.form1.zip.value.match(zipcode))  {
```

should be :

```
else  if((!document.form1.zip.value.match(zipcode)))  {
```

or:

```
else  if(!document.form1.zip.value.match(zipcode))  {
```

Always you should see browser console.you can see hint to get rid of your issues.